# If i`m isLogged abd refresh page, i will redirect on main page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I logging user before rendering page, but if user isLogged, and refresh page, he will redirect on main page.

It`s my frist redirect:

```
useEffect(() => {

    dispatch({type: USER_LOGIN})

}, [])

<PrivateRoute path={'/profile/:slug'} redirect={'/'} loggedIn={isLogged} component={Profile} />
```

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Comp, loggedIn, redirect, path, ...rest }) => {

    return (
        <Route
            path={path}
            {...rest}
            render={props => {
                return loggedIn ? <Comp {...props} /> : <Redirect to={redirect} />
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

And second try:

```
<Route path={'/profile/:slug'}>
       {
          isLogged ? <Route path={'/profile/:slug'} component={Profile} /> : <Redirect to={'/'} />
       }
</Route>
```

But all my try was wrong, and if i resfresh page, i was redirected on main page

Comment: You should probably have a "loading" state to conditionally render something *other* than your authenticated route component or redirect. I.e. wait for the auth check to complete before taking action one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in profile page this code in profile page

```
useEffect(() => {

       window.axios.post(`auth/user`)

            .then(res => {

                dispatch({type: USER_LOGIN, payload: res.data.data})

            })

            .catch(() => {

                history.push(`/`)

            })

    }, [])
```